# Android RecyclerView - clearOldPositions - NullPointerExceptions

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I've run into a very strange issue using the `RecyclerView` from the support package.

I have a `RecyclerView` inside a `ViewPager`. The moment the `ViewPager` shows the `RecyclerView`, the app crashes with the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.clearOldPositions(RecyclerView.java:2378)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:1968)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:2237)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
            at android.widget.ScrollView.onLayout(ScrollView.java:1468)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1594)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:890)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I can't find any sources about this on the internet, so if anyone's run into this before, any help would be appreciated.

Some background:

I'm importing the RecyclerView inside the build.gradle like so:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
```

I'm setting the Adapter and LayoutManager to the RecyclerView inside the RecyclerView's constructor like so:

```
    public CategoryParallaxView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CategoryParallaxView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CategoryParallaxView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init()
    {
        mLayoutManager = new CategoryParallaxLayoutManager();
        setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        mCategoryList = new ArrayList<CartCategory>();
        mAdapter = new CategoryParallaxAdapter();
        setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
```

When the `RecyclerView` is displayed, the size of the datasource (`mCategoryList`) is 0, but the list itself is not null.

The `RecyclerView` is nested inside a LinearLayout (which itself is nested inside a ScrollView), and has `MATCH_PARENT` defined in width and height. From some debugging, it seems like the width and height calculated for the `RecyclerView` are correct.

Not sure if this is relevant, but in my implementation, the `Adapter`, `ViewHolder` and `LayoutManager` subclasses are all private inner-classes of the my `RecyclerView` subclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the `RecyclerView` was clearing the `LayoutManager` that I was setting in the init method the moment the `RecyclerView` became visible in the `ViewPager`.

I fixed this by assigning the `LayoutManager` immediately after the `RecyclerView` became visible. It feels a bit hacky, but I can't find any other work around. If anyone can find a better solution, please post.